# When do you have to define a class in puppet?

Tags: puppet

I noticed that whenever classes are defined in puppet, they refer to external modules.

If you are doing something in site.pp and not referencing any external modules, would you ever still define a class?

Are classes necessary when referring to modules?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by external modules. What do you mean by "referring to modules?" `site.pp` contains your node definitions where you declare which modules get applied to particular nodes. Classes should be defined in the modules, whereas you declare them, or activate them in site.pp, either by a simple `include modulename`, or the equivalent class declaration style of `class {'modulename':}`. The later form allows you to pass in parameters, if needed.